# In Netbeans, "[Modified]" keeps showing and then going away on each file name

Tags: netbeans

How can I turn off this behavior?
Next to each file that is open is "filename" and then every second or so shows "[Modified]" next to each file name and then it goes away. This is really annoying and I'd like to stop it, but have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It annoyed me to no end too... :)

You are using some sort of code versioning system (SVN, Mercurial, Git,...) and NetBeans is telling you whether the file is commited or not. So when you commit the "Modified" label goes away. The solution below is written for Mercurial but should be similar for others too.

Solution: go to Tools > Options (Netbeans > Preferences on Mac), click Miscelaneous, choose Versioning tab, choose your code versioning system on the left (Mercurial), then remove "{status}" from "Mercurial status labels - format".

More information [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html#viewingFileStatus). Good luck! :)

Comment: I had to restart Netbeans after I did this, but it appears to be fixed now.Thank you!

Comment: Interesting... I didn't need to restart it (7.01), but it did take a few seconds to apply. You are welcome! :)